# Copy values of a mp3 tag to another tag for a batch of MP3 files

Tags: tags, mp3, swap, id3, id3-tag

I have a large MP3 directory and somehow the values of `album` tags (or `album names`) of the files (for all of them, hundreds) are actually the values of `artist` tags (or `artist names`) and vice-versa.

Now I have to copy the values from each other so that they are swapped for each and every single file in the directory. Or maybe I can just swap the tag names. I just want the `artist` tag to show artist names and `album` tags to show album name.

How should it be done as a batch edit?

Comment: I need to do this for ogg and flac, swapping artist and title respectively. On linux.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately tags for **mp3** is rather tricky but the following python script (requires the library **mutagen**) does the job for ogg and flac, solving my own problem at least.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# Copyright (c) 2011 kaleissin
# MIT License, see http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php

import mutagen
import os
import os.path

if len(sys.argv[1:]) < 1:
    print "Usage: %s <file> [file..]" % os.path.basename(__file__)

for filename in sys.argv[1:]:
    audio = mutagen.File(filename)
    audio['artist'], audio['title'] = audio['title'], audio['artist']
    audio.save()
```

Comment: I tried but it didn't work. I will try some modifications and update here if that works.

Answer (score 0):

**ID3 Mass Tagger** (https://github.com/squell/id3) should help. Works on Windows and Linux.

Swap artist and album fields in all mp3 files.

```
id3 -a %l -l %a "*.mp3"

Sets keys:
-a sets the artist key
-l sets the album key

Substitutes of current key values:
%t title
%a artist
%l album title
%n track number
%y year
%g genre
%c comment field
%f file name (without path)
%p path to filename
```

Use on a sample first.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the **mid3cp** [tool](https://mutagen.readthedocs.io/en/latest/man/mid3cp.html) from the python-mutagen library which does exactly what you are looking for.

Under Ubuntu it is not installed by default but if you simply put the content of [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/quodlibet/mutagen/master/tools/mid3cp) file in `/usr/bin` and make it executable it works.

Comment: "This file" no longer exists.